# grid header will be hide in p-dialog during minimize the browser

Tags: html, css, angular, dialog, primeng

Go to this primeng [dialog box article](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dynamicdialog)

See this below image when I open the dialog box

[image]

> But the problem is grid header will be hide during  minimize the browser

[image]

I am using the dialog box all over into my application. My project is going to live at this weekend. But I should solve this before go to live. Could you please anyone  fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `.ui-dialog { z-index: 1001;}` inline `z-index` using `!important` as shown below:

```
.ui-dialog {
 z-index: 9999!important;
}
```

This is because of id `#layout-topbar` z-index is bigger than `ui-dialog` so you need to override `ui-dialog` `z-index` using `!important`. hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
.ui-dynamicdialog { 
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 100000;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    opacity: 1;
    margin: 30px 0;
}
```

Adjust css per your requirement. Calculate top and set it here

Comment: What you mean by `ui-dynamicdialog`? where I need to add?

Comment: Inspect sample of primeng on its website. It is default class added primeng dialog

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> body .ui-dialog {
>       z-index: 9999;}

Answer (score 0):

Use `baseZIndex` property for `DynamicDialog` and set its value more than `#layout-topbar` value which is `9998`

```
const ref = this.dialogService.open(CarsListDemo, {
    header: 'Choose a Car',
    width: '70%',
    baseZIndex: 9999 //Base zIndex value to use in layering
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Resizing the browser window wont give optimal results for responsive view. I checked your page and css. Everything looks fine and there is no issue.

But, when you resize the browser, popup appears as if grid header is hidden under page header. Reason behind this is, grid popup is in fixed position, so it will calculate the total height of browser window and appears center to it.

Try viewing this using **Toggle Device Toolbar(Ctrl+Shift+M)** and your popup looks exactly at the center vertically and horizontally. 
Below image for your reference.

[image]